# Change $_SESSION with $.ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session

The actual page launch an `$.ajax (POST)` request and the `receiver.php` need to modify the `$_SESSION`.
However it do not work, i don't know whether the `id` of `$_SESSION` is different or if i need a refresh on the page for register the modification.

I tried to transfer the session id and modifiy it with :

```
<?php
    if ( count( $_POST ) > 1 && isset( $_POST["s"] ) )
    {
        session_id( $_POST["s"] );
        session_start();
    }
?>
```

but this code is ineffective...

My `$.ajax` request is simple :

```
var s = <?php echo "'" . session_id() . "'"; ?>;

$.ajax({
    url: 'jquery/receiver.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        s: s, // session id, useless?
        // data...
    },
}).done(function ( data ) {
    // operations ...
}
```

My `receiver.php` too ;

```
<?php
    if ( count( $_POST ) > 1 && isset( $_POST["s"] ) )
    {
        session_id( $_POST["s"] );
        session_start();
    }

    $_SESSION['longarray']['key'] = 'value';
?>
```

Finally, it is possible to modify `$_SESSION` with `$.ajax (POST)` ? Or maybe i have only a problem because my `$_SESSION` is a `array` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I tried the following
testp1.php

```
    <?PHP
        session_start();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../common/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var s = '<?php echo session_id(); ?>';

        $.ajax({
            url: 'receiver.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                s: s, // session id, useless?
                // data...
            },
            success: function(data){ console.log(data); }
        })
    })
    </script>
    <body>
    <?PHP
        echo $_SESSION['longarray']['key'];
    ?>
    </body>
```

ajax call to receiver.php

```
<?php
    if ( count( $_POST ) >= 1 && isset( $_POST["s"] ) )
    {
        session_id( $_POST["s"] );
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['longarray']['key'] = 'mix';
    }
    else
        echo "ERROR";;
?>
```

On testp1.php the body shows `mix`

Comment: Not really... because a `$_SESSION id` can be 'bba31afe537857688b692fa9bb8df746', so a string.

Comment: sorry yup realized the blunder after posting!

Comment: Thank you for your time ! Ok, maybe my bug occurs because i use `array` in `$_SESSION`..

Comment: I would just like to point that if you set the `$_SESSION['longarray']['key']` on testp1.php then the output would be the value on testp1.php and not the value set in receiver.php

Answer (score 0):

I found my error with the help of [rakesh219](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3590880/rakesh219) !

In my code, i introduced stupid lines like :

```
if ( ! isset( $_SESSION['akey'], $_SESSION['akey']['anotherkey'] ) {
    $_SESSION['akey'] = new array();
    $_SESSION['akey']['anotherkey'] = new array();
}
```

i have removed it and it is fixed !